# qsort() - compare function parameter

Tags: c, pointers, qsort

Lets say I have a struct called `Student`.

```
typedef struct student {
    int age;
    char name[10];
} Student;
```

And I have an array of pointers to Students.

```
Student *a[10];
```

I need to sort the array by the names of the students. So I wrote the comparison function:

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b){
    Student *temp1=*(Student **)a;
    Student *temp2=*(Student **)b;
    return strcmp(temp1->name, temp2->name);
}
```

Then I have the function to sort:

```
void SortArray(Student *a[], int len){
    qsort(a, len, sizeof(Student *), *compare*);
    printArray(a);
}
```

The last part of the qsort is what I don't get. I saw some posts where they wrote `&compare`, and some where they don't. Only when I used `&compare` it worked.
How do I know whether to use `&` or not?

Comment: Functions are similar to arrays in one way: If the function is used when a pointer to a function, it will *decay* to a pointer. It's usually safe to use e.g. `compare` only, but I recommend you use `&compare` to make it more explicit for the readers of the code.

Comment: You don't need any decoration, just pass `compare`.

Comment: `&compare` is explicit/readable in exactly the same way `&array[0]` is: confusing and gratuitously ugly to anyone who knows the language. Just use `compare` or `array`. Note that **every time you call a function**, as in `func(x)`, the name `func` is decaying to a pointer because the `()` operator (function call) requires a function pointer as its operand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name of the function referenced to the function, you can use the name of the function. Also, as mentioned in comments, `&` is ok to reference too.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to call the function like for example:)

```
qsort(a, len, sizeof(Student *), ***********compare);
```

or like

```
qsort(a, len, sizeof(Student *), &***********compare);
```

According to the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 4 A function designator is an expression that has function type.
>   Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator65) or the unary &
>   operator, a function designator with type **‘‘function returning
>   type’’ is converted to an expression that has type ‘‘pointer to
>   function returning type’’**.

So in this expression

```
***********compare
```

the function designator `compare` is implicitly converted to function pointer then applying the dereferencing it is in turn converted to the function type and then again to function pointer and so on.

Of course you can explicitly specify `&compare` though it is not necessary.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(void)
{
    puts("Hello eitanmayer");
}

void g(void f(void))
{
    f();
}

int main( void )
{
    g(&******f);
}
```

Its output is

```
Hello eitanmayer
```

So the problem with your code can be somewhere else.